# big sql query - best practice

Tags: php, mysql, session

my php script save list of userid in a SESSION  ARRAY variable for the purpose of creating html link on that page.

when we click that html link another `PHP` script  should display all user information for that userid in a html table.

I need yo know best practice to create `SELECT` query for this

```
1) SELECT * from `users` WHERE  
`user_id` = '$array_valuer1' OR 
`user_id` = '$array_valuer2' OR 
`user_id` = '$array_valuer3' OR 
`user_id` = '$array_valuer4' OR 
`user_id` = '$array_valuer5' OR 
`user_id` = '$array_valuer6' OR 
----
----
`user_id` = '$array_valuern';

2) select all user --> SELECT * from `users`
   then using php script display only the userid in the SESSION array and skip other userid
```

which is best practice? the SESSION array is temporary and i do not to want to save in a database.

thanks

Comment: What are you trying? What exactly you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing few user ids in a session its okay. But if the number is huge dont store them in SESSION. Its better to fetch them using a query.

About the query you can use following form.

```
$q = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE `user_id` IN ('".implode("','", $array)."')";
```

Comment: thanks all for your reply. what in the maximum user-id can i use here?

Comment: maximum number of user ids? Just dont store them in session. Fetch them from DB. you must know the criteria for with they existing in a users session, right? use that criteria to load it from DB. if you save your session in DB it'll be fetched from DB. So its same.

Answer (score 1):

shiplu.mokadd.im answer is good, but using PDO is better:

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `user_id` IN (':list')");
$statement->execute(array(':list' => implode("','", $array)));
$row = $statement->fetch();
```